# C# CSV file to array/list

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csv-import

I want to read 4-5 CSV files in some array in C#

I  know that this question is been asked and I have gone through them...
But my use of CSVs is too much simpler for that...

I have csv fiels with columns of following  data types....

`string , string`

These strings are without ',' so no tension...
That's it. And they aren't much big. Only about 20 records in each.

I **just** want to **read** them into array of C#....

Is there any *very very simple* and *direct* way to do that?

Comment: Look at the **Related** questions over there -->

Comment: What's an 'array of C#'?

Comment: @GrantThomas: A fistful of spectacles? (could be a new Clint Eastwood movie about desperadoes facing the ravages of old age and poor eyesight)

Answer (score 3):

To read the file, use

```
TextReader reader = File.OpenText(filename);
```

To read a line:

```
string line = reader.ReadLine()
```

then

```
string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
```

to separate them.

By using a loop around the two last example lines, you could add each array of tokens into a list, if that's what you need.

Comment: What if a column entry contains a comma within the string value?

Comment: Well, if the CSV-file is comma separated, comma's within the token are either illegal, or they are impossible to parse right. The delimiting character should obviously be a character that is not used in the tokens.

If the topic started uses commas in his cells, I would assume that he wouldn't export to a comma separated list!

Comment: That is entirely false, and as a programmer I'd expect one to know _something_ of escaping values.

Comment: Given a CSV file that contains only this:
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
You you know that these come from 2 cells. How would you know which letters originate from which cells?

Comment: `a,'a,b,c,d,e,f,g'` ... or there could be a custom farse going on, `a,a\,b\,c\,d\,e\,f\,g`. Admittedly weird, but for this purpose let's assume it's out of scope to handle how input should be displayed and only need to parse correctly, with slashes and all... but _still_ only with that string as a single value.

Comment: This would depend on the source of the CSV file. If the export escapes the characters, fine! And that makes your whole argumentation moot since it answers your own original question. If it doesn't we are still out of luck.

Comment: No it doesn't, your code would break the output in such a case.

Answer (score 3):

This one includes the quotes & commas in fields. (assumes you're doing a line at a time)

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;   //For TextFieldParser

// blah blah blah

StringReader csv_reader = new StringReader(csv_line);

TextFieldParser csv_parser = new TextFieldParser(csv_reader);
csv_parser.SetDelimiters(",");
csv_parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
string[] csv_array = csv_parser.ReadFields();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to get a CSV content to an array of strings. The CSV file can have double quotes, carriage return line feeds and the delimiter is a comma.
Here are the libraries that you need:

`System.IO;`
`System.Collection.Generic;`

`System.IO` is for `FileStream` and `StreamReader` class to access your file. Both classes implement the `IDisposable` interface, so you can use the `using` statements to close your streams. (example below)

`System.Collection.Generic` namespace is for collections, such as `IList`,`List`, and `ArrayList`, etc... In this example, we'll use the `List` class, because Lists are better than Arrays in my honest opinion. However, before I return our outbound variable, i'll call the `.ToArray()` member method to return the array.

There are many ways to get content from your file, I personally prefer to use a `while(condition)` loop to iterate over the contents. In the `condition` clause, use `!lReader.EndOfStream`. While **not** end of stream, continue iterating over the file.

```
public string[] GetCsvContent(string iFileName)
{
    List<string> oCsvContent = new List<string>();
    using (FileStream lFileStream = 
                  new FileStream(iFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        StringBuilder lFileContent = new StringBuilder();
        using (StreamReader lReader = new StreamReader(lFileStream))
        {
            // flag if a double quote is found
            bool lContainsDoubleQuotes = false; 
            // a string for the csv value
            string lCsvValue = "";
            // loop through the file until you read the end
            while (!lReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                // stores each line in a variable
                string lCsvLine = lReader.ReadLine();
                // for each character in the line...
                foreach (char lLetter in lCsvLine)
                {
                    // check if the character is a double quote
                    if (lLetter == '"')
                    {
                        if (!lContainsDoubleQuotes)
                        {
                            lContainsDoubleQuotes = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lContainsDoubleQuotes = false;
                        }
                    }
                    // if we come across a comma 
                    // AND it's not within a double quote..
                    if (lLetter == ',' && !lContainsDoubleQuotes)
                    {
                        // add our string to the array
                        oCsvContent.Add(lCsvValue);
                        // null out our string
                        lCsvValue = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // add the character to our string
                        lCsvValue += lLetter;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return oCsvContent.ToArray();
}
```

Hope this helps! Very easy and very quick.
Cheers!